# Why is $e^{x}$ not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

It seems intuitively very clear that $e^{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. I'm looking to 'prove' it using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ analysis though. I reason as follows:

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$; in fact, fix it to be $\epsilon=1$.

For contradiction, suppose that $\exists \delta >0$ s.t. $$ (\star) \ |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |e^{x}-e^{y}|<\epsilon=1 \text{  for  } x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Note that $e^{x+\delta}-e^{x}=e^{x}(e^{\delta}-1)$. So, for $x$ large enough (so that RHS $>1$), the relation $(\star)$ does not hold.

This is our contradiction, and so the exponential function is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this reasoning correct and sufficient?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks mostly good to me, but I would suggest instead of fixing $\varepsilon>0$ to be $\varepsilon=1$, just let it be arbitrary, and then calculate exactly how large $x$ has to be... something like $\ln\left(\frac{2\varepsilon}{e^\delta-1}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks @Clayton for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are truly looking for a rigorous answer then you need to justify the "So, for $x$ large enough...".

For instance, here is a very rigorous solution along the lines you suggest:

Assume that $e^x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb {R}$. Let $\epsilon = 1$. Thus there is $\delta >0$ such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$ if $|x-y|<\delta $ then $|e^x-e^y| < 1$. Let $a=\delta/2$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty }e^x=\infty$ and since $e^a-1>0$ it follows that $\lim_{x\to \infty }e^x(e^a-1)=\infty$. Consequently, there is some $x\in \mathbb {R}$ such that $e^x(e^a-1)>1$. However, taking $y=x+a$ we have $|x-y|<\delta$ while $|e^x-e^y|=e^x(e^a-1)>1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, I see it. This is the rigour I was looking for.

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: @IttayWeiss Can we also do this using the sequences $\log n$ and $\log (n+1)$?

Answer (score 5):

Your proof looks good to me. There are only a few technicalities:

1. You should consider an arbitrary $\delta>0$ because the contrapositive of
   $$\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0,\ \forall|x-y|<\delta,\ |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$
   is
   $$\exists \epsilon>0,\ \forall\delta>0,\ \exists|x-y|<\delta,\ |f(x)-f(y)|\ge\epsilon.$$
2. You should consider something like $e^{x+\delta/2}-e^x$ rather than $e^{x+\delta}-e^x$ because $|(x+\delta)-x|$ is not smaller than $\delta$.
3. As Clayton pointed out in the comment section, if you claim that $(\star)$ does not hold when $x$ is large enough, you'd better explicitly write down an instance of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove that $e^{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ using an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument is to consider a fairly rigid consequence of this class of functions by means of the following result:

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous then there exists constants $A, B >0$ such that $|f(x)|< A|x| +B$ $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

**Proof:** Take $\varepsilon =1$ in the definition of uniform continuity so that there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $|x-y|< \delta $, then $|f(x)-f(y)|< 1.$ In particular, setting $y=0$ and using the triangle inequality, we get that $|x|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)|< |f(0)|+1 < |f(0)|+1 + |x| = A_{1}|x| + B_{1}$, where $A_{1}=1$ and $B_{1}= |f(0)|+1.$

Now suppose $|x| \geq \delta$ and WLOG let $x >0$ (the case of $x<0$ uses a similar argument.) Set $n = \lfloor \frac{2x}{\delta}\rfloor$ so that $0 \leq x - \frac{n\delta}{2} \leq \frac{\delta}{2}.$ From $0,$ we then approach $x$ in $n$ steps of $\frac{\delta}{2}$ and use uniform continuity on the intervals $(\frac{i\delta}{2}, \frac{(i+1)\delta}{2})$as follows:

$\begin{align}|f(x)-f(0)|&\leq \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left|f\left(\frac{i\delta}{2}\right)- f\left(\frac{(i+1)\delta}{2}\right)\right|+ \left|f\left(\frac{n \delta}{2}\right)- f(x)\right| \\&\leq n+1\\&= \frac{2x}{\delta} +1\end{align}$

$\Rightarrow |f(x)|< |f(0)|+1+\frac{2x}{\delta}$

Repeating this argument for the $x\leq -\delta$ case and setting $A= \max\{A_{1}, \frac{\delta}{2}\}$ and $B = B_{1}$, the proof is complete.

Using this result, we can immediately see that $f(x)= e^x$ is not uniformly continuous or else we would have $e^x < A|x| +B$, which is an obvious contradiction for large $x.$ This argument also shows that non-linear polynomials and other fast-growing functions like $\tan(x)$ are not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, let us assume that $e^{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. So by

def, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$, such that $|e^{x}-e^{y}| < \epsilon$ 
whenever $|x-y| < \delta$.

Now let $x=n+\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $y=n$, clearly x and y are close enough so that,

$|e^{x}-e^{y}| < \epsilon$

by mean value theorem we got,

$e^{\zeta}.|x-y|=|e^{x}-e^{y}| < \epsilon$,  where $y < \zeta < x$

as $e^{x}$ is increasing function we must have $e^{n} = e^{y} < e^{\zeta}$, hence

$e^{n} . \frac{\delta}{2} < e^{\zeta}|x-y| =|e^{x}-e^{y}| < \epsilon$

$e^{n}<\frac{2.\epsilon}{\delta}$, which is a contradiction as $e^{n}$ tends to infinity as n tend.