# Prove that $a^x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, exponentiation

I'm having trouble with proving the following:

Let $a > 0$ be a positive real number. Show that the function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := a^x$ is continuous.

I'm a first year mathematics student, so I am trying to prove this in a way that is understandable to me, a delta epsilon proof. Could you help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of $a^x$?

Comment: Hint:  Notice that $|x-y|<\log_a(\epsilon+1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $|a^x-a^y|<\epsilon$ (or something like that)

Comment: Do you know, that $a^x = \exp(x \log(a))$? If you know that the exponential function $\exp$ is continuous, it should not be difficult to show that $x \mapsto a^x$ is continuous.

Comment: draw the function and then select $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and mark their image with perpendicular lines to axis, in $f(x)$ draw a little circle and look for $f^{-1}(circle)$ you will find an circle around x, now pick the point more closer to x of the little circumference, that point will be $x-\delta$ If is in the left of $x$ or $x+\delta$ if is in right, try drawing what I've written . Pst: use $log_a$ to find the value of $\delta$.

Comment: We are not allowed to use log, because we didn't prove it's definition yet in our analyse class. But thanks for the effort so far!

Comment: @Peter But how did you define $a^x$?

Comment: @Alex $a$ to the power $x$. So $a$ times $a$ times $a$ times $a$... and that $x$ times

Comment: @Peter: But this doesn't work here, you have a function on $\mathbb R$, so $x$ can be $\frac 1 2$ or even an irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$. How did you define $a^x$ for this case?

Comment: Seems to me it's gonna be hard to pick a log-independent $\delta$...

Comment: See, for example, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284663/why-is-ex-not-uniformly-continuous-on-mathbbr) question--your $\delta$ is going to have to be a function of both $x_0$ (the point at which you're trying to prove continuity) and $\varepsilon$. On an intuitive level, the slopes of the tangents of $a^x$ are going to $\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that involves logs; you're going to have to go far out of your way to do so otherwise.

Take $a>1$ WLOG -- if $a<1$, this is just a reflection of an $a>1$ (you should be able to prove that if $f$ is continuous, then $g(x)=f(-x)$ is also continuous pretty easily).

The key is to look for an $x-x_0$ in the function image expression--here that's done by factoring: $a^x-a^{x_0}=a^{x_0}(a^{x-x_0}-1)$. Intuitively now, we know we can make the second element of the product small because we have direct control in choosing $\delta$ over $x-x_0$; the key is to notice that we must *also* account for the size of $a^{x_0}$ (which is why this function is not *uniformly* continuous, but that's for another day).

Let's play around with image distance a bit:

$$ \left| a^x-a^{x_0} \right| = \left| a^{x_0} \left( a^{x-x_0} - 1 \right) \right| \leq a^{x_0} \left| a^{x-x_0} - 1 \right| $$

It may take some convincing, but you should prove to yourself that $ |a^y-1| \leq a^{|y|}-1 $ (for starters, look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%282%5Ex-1%29+and+2%5Eabs%28x%29-1) for at least graphic proof that it works--note that I'm implicitly using that $a>1$).

Thus, $ \left| a^x - a^{x_0} \right| \leq a^{x_0} \left( a^{|x-x_0|} - 1 \right ) $, where we see exactly what we want: $|x-x_0|$.

Now we pick the $\delta$ that will turn the RHS above into just $\varepsilon$--we can do this by setting

$$\delta = \log_a \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{a^{x_0}} + 1 \right) $$

So that:

$\left| a^x-a^{x_0} \right| < \varepsilon $ whenever $|x-x_0|$ is strictly smaller than our chosen $\delta$.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late comment. You mentioned you'd have to go far out of your way to not use logs. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

> Hey, if you are starting in maths you must use a lot of your imagination, everytime you can, try to draw your problem, I hope it helps you, pick $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$
>   [image]

Comment: Could you tell me what software you used to draw that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i'm using TexStudio, i wrote this in LaTeX code.
Hola, usé TexStudio, lo escribí en código de LaTeX

Comment: I won't understand the $\delta$ which is displayed in the image .please explain it.

Comment: @SathasivamK : if te Orange ball has coordinates $f(x)-\epsilon$ and $f(x)+\epsilon$, then $\delta_1$ is such that $f(x-\delta_1)=f(x)-\epsilon$ and $\delta_2$ such that $f(x+\delta_2)=f(x)+\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

The following is answer without relying on log:

$f(x) := a^x$

$$|a^x - a^{x_0} = a^{x_0}|a^{x - x_0} - 1|$$

Choose $$N \in \mathbb{R}\ : \ \frac{1}{N} \leq x - x_0 \leq \frac{1}{N - 1}$$

It follows:

$$|a^{-N} - 1| \leq |a^{x - x_0} - 1| \leq |a^{-(N + 1)} - 1| $$

As $x \rightarrow x_0$ we have $a^{-N} - 1$ and $a^{-(N + 1)} - 1$ approaches 0.

Therefore by squeeze theorem we have :

$$lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} |a^x - a^x_0| = a^{x_0}|a^{x - x_0} - 1| = 0$$

Answer (score -1):

For any positive real number a, a<sup>x</sup> is defined to mean exp(x ln a) where ln is the inverse of exp. It can be shown that for any 2 functions f and g, if f is continuous on R and g is a linear function with nonzero slope, f ∘ g is continuous so for any positive real number a, if exp(x) is continuous on R, then exp(x ln a) is continuous on R but a<sup>x</sup> = exp(x ln a) so a<sup>x</sup> is continuous on R if exp(x) is continuous on R. Exp(x) is defined to be the unique function with domain R that both is its own derivative and assigns 1 to 0. It can be shown that a function with that property exists because 1 + x + x<sup>2</sup>/2! + x<sup>3</sup>/3! + x<sup>4</sup>/4! ... has that property. It can also be shown that the any function with that property has an inverse with domain (0, ∞) and derivative 1/x over its domain that assigns 0 to 1 but according to https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zero_Derivative_implies_Constant_Function, all functions that have a 0 derivative in any interval are constant in that interval, so any two functions with domain R that are their own derivative and assign 1 to 0 must have the same inverse and so must be the same function. Therefore, there is exactly one funtion from R to R that's its own derivative and assigns 1 to 0, so we can call it exp(x). Finally, for any x, for any δ in interval (0, exp(x)), we can chose ɛ = δ/2exp(x) and the exp of any real number within (x - ɛ, x + ɛ) will be within (exp(x) - δ, exp(x) + δ) so by definition exp(x) is continuous. Finally, since exp(x) is continuous, a<sup>x</sup> is continuous for any positive real number a.

Comment: Please use $\mathrm\LaTeX$.