# Negation of uniform continuity for $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that $f(x)=e^x$ is not uniformly continuous on the set of all non-negative reals. I write the negation of the corresp. definition as follows: there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta >0$ there are $x\ge 0$ and $h>0$ such that $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon$ and $h< \delta$ hold simultaneously.

That is, I must show that for some $x\ge 0 $ and $h>0$, the quantity $|e^{x+h}-e^x|=e^x|e^h-1|$ can be made greater than some $\epsilon$, even though $h$ is arbitrarily small. How do I do that?

Comment: related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284663/why-is-ex-not-uniformly-continuous-on-mathbbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h$ just has to be a particular number smaller than $\delta$, so we can take $h=\delta/2$. Then $e^{\delta/2}-1>\delta/2$ since $t \mapsto e^t$ is convex. So now choose $x$ large enough that
$$ e^{x} \delta/2 \geq \epsilon, $$
i.e.
$$ x \geq \log{\left( \frac{2\epsilon}{\delta} \right)}. $$
Since we have available arbitrarily large $x$, one can do this for any positive $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: How do you use convexity to establish the inequality you mentioned? Alternatively, can I prove it by saying that $e^x-1=\sum_{k\ge 1}x^k/k!$, which is greater than $x$ for $x$ positive?

Comment: That would also work, for positive $x$. Point with convexity is that $e^x$ lies above its tangent line, and at $x=0$ is that is $1+x$. It's better than the series proof because it works for all $x$, although that's not necessary here. An intermediate version is to use a Taylor series with remainder, such as $e^x = 1 + x + \int_{0}^x (x-t)e^{t} \, dt$, and it is easy to check that the integral term is always nonnegative.